# Paste specific excel range in outlook meeting

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to run a macro from excel to copy and paste a specific range into a meeting invite. I tried to edit Ron de Bruin's code.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "bob@bob.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

It works well but when I change

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

to

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
```

The meeting invite opens but the range that gets pasted doesn't come over.

Any help you can provide would be a life saver.

Comment: Remove the On Error Resume Next just before With OutMail. "On Error Resume Next , is the most commonly used and **misused** form.  It instructs to VBA to essentially ignore the error and resume execution on the next line of code. It is very important to remember that On Error Resume Next does not in any way "fix" the error."  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: I tried removing the "on error resume next".  When I do so, I get other error messages such as Type mismatch" cannot coerce parameter value.  Outlook cannot translate your string."  Should I change the "on error to something else"?

Comment: After as well removing .To, .CC and .BCC you should see Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method at the line ".HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)".

Comment: I want to keep that RangetoHTML portion.  It is a table that has deadlines and descriptions.  That table is what I want to copy into the body of the meeting invite.  I also want to include the .to recipients that are listed in another cell.  Is it possible?

Comment: Also, thanks for trying to help.  I have hit a wall at this point.  not sure what to do

Comment: i think it is because you cannot put HTML into a meeting invite.  Is there a way to copy the range to a clipboard and paste it into the meeting invite?  Or maybe instead of doing rangetoHTML do a rangetoRTF type format?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Meeting_Invites()

Dim UsrName As String, Docpath As String
Dim Rpt As String
Dim openpath As String, NameVal As String
Dim PDFPath As String
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Dim exclapp As Excel.Application
Set exclapp = Excel.Application
Set ObjMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim Mymail As Outlook.AppointmentItem

UsrName = Environ("USERNAME")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If olApp.Session.Offline = False Then

    MsgBox "Please go offline, before running the macro to generate mails"
    Exit Sub

    Else

End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Select

Range("A1").Select

DataCount = ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

On Error GoTo ExitPlace:

For a = 2 To DataCount

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 30) = a
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    ActiveSheet.Range("Ac3:Ad26").Copy

    'Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("Ac3:Ad26")

    Set Mymail = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    Mymail.Display

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection

    Set objItem = Mymail
    Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
    Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
    Set objWord = objDoc.Application
    Set objSel = objWord.Selection

    objSel.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

    Set Rng = Sheets("Welcome").Cells

    If Rng(a, 3).Value <> "" Then
        With Mymail
            .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(j, 3).Value

        End With
    End If

    If Rng(a, 4).Value <> "" Then
        With Mymail
            .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(j, 4).Value
        End With
    End If

    If Rng(a, 5).Value <> "" Then
        With Mymail
            .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(j, 5).Value
        End With
    End If

     With Mymail
          .Recipients.Add Rng(a, 1).Value
          '.SentOnBehalfOfName = Rng(a, 2).Value
          .Subject = Rng(a, 6).Value
          .Location = Rng(a, 7).Value
          .Start = Rng(a, 8).Value
          .Duration = 90
          .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
          '.Send
          '.Close (olSave)

    End With

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next

On Error GoTo 0

Set Mymail = Nothing
Set exclapp = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Select
Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Dear " & UsrName & ":" & " Please check the Calendar Space for Meeting Invites"

Exit Sub

ExitPlace:
    If Err.Number = 4605 Then
        MsgBox "Error Pasting the Mail content to the Meeting body, Please contact Developer or Try Running the Macro Again."
        Mymail.Close (olDiscard)

Else

    MsgBox "The process got some error at row " & a & " Please check and run again"
   Resume
    Mymail.Close (olDiscard)
End If

'    Resume

End Sub
```

Comment: The above code works perfectly to copy the desired range of data from Excel to meeting invite, but fails sometime. I am unable to figure why it fails to paste data  some times and goes well on other instances.